# selecting the appropriate text field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table in which data looks like this:

```
<td><%= f.text_area(:add1, {rows: 6, cols: 20, :class => "update_address"})%></td>
<td><%= f.text_area(:add2, {rows: 6, cols: 20, :class => "update_address"})%></td>
<td><%= f.text_area(:add3, {rows: 6, cols: 20, :class => "update_address"})%></td>
```

When i click on any text field, a dialog box should open for that text field. I have tried:

```
$( ".update_address #" + this.id ).click(function() 
  {
    $( "#dialog-form1" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
```

but it  doesnt work. please help me.

Comment: how are you finding this.id in the method

Comment: why not just: `$( ".update_address" ).click(...);` ? What is expected result? What is current result? Etc...

Comment: where are the dialogs?

Answer (score 1):

*Updated*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.update_address').click(function () {
       //$(this).val(); //The chosen textbox value
       // Now you can do whatever you like with it 
       $("spansIdInDialog").text($(this).val()); 
   });

})
```

Comment: No i have only one dialog box. I don't know how to proceed.
Please tell me.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "a dialog box should open for that text field"?  Update your question with relevant information.

Comment: I want the dialog box just to update the value to the respective text_field. There is just one dialog box

Comment: please provide me suggestions atleast.I need it immediately.

Comment: What are you trying to put in the text fields?  Dialogs dont update anything.

Comment: Its a pop-up box where i add the address lines and display them in the chosen textbox. Help